# Get the string before a specific character

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query which return the target name in the below format:
Database_hostname_instance
I need to extract the below part only from this:
Database_hostname
For this i tried to use the below ,but it gives the string before the initial '*' like 'Database
regexp_substr(target_name, '^[^*]+')

Can you please suggest how to get the string before the 1st occurance of '_' from the end.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always two underscores, you can use:

```
select regexp_replace('Database_hostname_instance', '_[^_]*$', '')
from dual
```

This lops off the last underscore and everything after it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `INSTR` function

```
select 'Database_hostname_instance', substr('Database_hostname_instance', 0, 
instr('Database_hostname_instance', '_', -1)-1)
from dual;
```